# Xamarin Android Manifest.xml ${applicationId} error on build

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I am new in Xamarin. I am working on FCM and unable to resolve an issue in manifest.xml regarding applicationId. On build VS automatically replace ${applicationId} with APP ID in the receiver tag. My APP ID contains ':' in it and while building my project i received this error:

> Tag ***category*** attribute name has invalid character ':'
>
> APP ID: 1:155007225:android:31f4cbf34842713c6f7b

Receiver Code:

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="1:155007225:android:31f4cbf34842713c6f7b" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="md5a2380a28141411635d1963b62f9f05b7.MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<service android:name="md5a2380a28141411635d1963b62f9f05b7.MyFirebaseIIDService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
<provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="FCM.FCM.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
<!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
<receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
    <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.FCM.FCM" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

If you can see my code has ***category*** tag under ***intent-filter*** tag

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you please share the code of `Manifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of app id that you get from Firebase, you need to use the Package Name as applicationId, please refer to [Set the Package Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows#start-an-app-project)

> In Firebase Cloud Messaging, you specified a package name for the
>   FCM-enabled app. This package name also serves as the application ID
>   that is associated with the API key. Configure the app to use this
>   package name

**update:**

Try  the following code instead:

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" 
android:exported="true" 
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
 <intent-filter>
  ....
    <category android:name="${applicationId}"
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I am using the same documentation you have shared but here is a thing. I replaced my app_id with package name but VS automatically replace it with app_id on build and still got that error.

Comment: My manifest.xml was same as you updated. I think you didn't get that. If you see pint number 3 that documentation under "This XML does the following:" The Xamarin.Android Firebase bindings will replace the token ${applicationId} with the app ID;

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your question,maybe you can try use `<category android:name="applicationId"/>` . Or  `<category android:name="yourpackagename"/>`

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: I am afraid that this can't be possible. you can create xamarin android project and add FCM using the same documentation you've posted.

Comment: Sorry, so late to reply, have you got the answer?

Comment: Nope. Do you got any solution?

Comment: Sorry, we couldn't repruduce this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code for receiver :

```
<application android:label="YourAppName">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Nope. Still the same error. Whenever i build my project VS automatically replace ${applicationId} with actual application ID and that App Id contains colon ':' and my manifest.xml file not ignoring it. Stuck here...